# There is any Macro Recorder for Web Page fetching automation?

Tags: automation, selenium, httpwebrequest, browser

[Selenium HQ](http://seleniumhq.org/) records some web navigation and can replay it from Firefox. I want a similar thing, but it must have an API.

** UPDATE ** It turns out that Selenium has an API, but I will keep the question since there are alternatives.

My objective is to fetch a web page periodically and save its contents to a database. The web content is not so easy to fetch because it requires some cookies and viewstate, otherwise it won't respond properly.

BTW I'm a .NET developer, and I thought of using System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser, but I didn't try it yet.

Comment: What problems are you having with WebBrowser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selenium IDE does record-and-play, but Selenium RC (with an API) runs pre-written tests. Also, there are various client languages such as Java, Python, C#, etc. Tests can be run against multiple browsers.

Alternatively you could use Webdriver, which is a similar project and will ultimately be merged into Selenium 2.0

Selenium RC: http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/

Webdriver: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted

Answer (score 1):

UiPath includes a [macro recorder](http://www.uipath.com/automate/macro-recorder) and it has an API for connecting to databases.